# Scroll event getting fired on top element as well as on the bottom element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-virtualized

I'm using `AutoSizer` for one of the use cases in my application. in Autosizer code, they change the scrollTop due to which the scroll event is getting triggered. As the scroll events are captured (and not bubbled), how do I prevent scroll event in AutoSizer (or restrict the event only to the desired element)? The one way I could find is, checking if the `target` and `currentTarget` is same in the event handler

```
onScroll = event => {
    if(event.target === event.currentTarget){
        ...do Something
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to do it or there is some other way? 
P.S. I'm using `react` in my application

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to prevent scrolling on a parent component if child component has been scrolled. If yes, so use `e.stopPropagation();` for it.

```
onScroll = event => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // ...do Something
}
```

Comment: But the scroll event is captured and not bubbled. In that case, stopPropagation doesn't make any sense

Comment: @AjayGaur, then, your solution is correct. I would use the same. [useful link](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)